# Is there any function to sort a std::vector< cv::Point2f> vector

Tags: c++, opencv

is there any opencv function or a combination of functions that can sort a

`std::vector< cv::Point2f>`

I've tried with std::sort and cv::sort  it didn't help !

Comment: Use std::sort but pass in a predicate to sort on.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to use the order for, but with floating points you might have problems ordering points like cv::Point2f(1.0f+epsilon,0.0f) cv::Point2f(1.0f,20.0f) cv::Point2f(1.0f-epsilon,40.0f) : do not expect a very specific behaviour if you define your ordering function: `return (a.x < b.x) ? true : (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to define how to compare `cv::Point2f` to each other. You can pass a `lambda` to `std::sort`:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), 
          [](const cv::Point2f &a, const cv::Point2f &b)
          {
              return a.x < b.x; //or whatever you like
          });
```

In case `lambda` is not supported you can pass just a regular function or functor.